# typescript callback function return function

Tags: typescript

I have function take function as argument and return new function. Returned function called with `options` params and call `styleCallback` function. 
I dont know how to pass `options` type to `styleCallback`

```
const makeStyle = (styleCallback) => {
    return (options) =>{
        theme = getTheme();
        return styleCallback(theme, options)
    }
}
```

I tried with generics but it not worked

```
const makeStyle = (styleCallback: (theme: Theme, props: T) => any) => {
    return <T>(options: T) =>{
        theme = getTheme();
        return styleCallback(theme, options)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the type variable in the main function should resolve your issue.

```
const makeStyle = <T>(styleCallback: (theme: Theme, props: T) => any) => {
    return (options: T) => {
        let theme = getTheme();
        return styleCallback(theme, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it  and typescript ok about it but props properties is not recognized in `styleCallback`. `makeStyle((theme, props) => 3})({size: 12})` , `props.size` not accesible

Comment: You need the <T> on your styleCallback as well.

Comment: yes i tried exactly same in your answer, but options 'unknown'. [pls check here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygFQBYILYJgXhgCgEocA+fAb1ABsQAnALhgHIBPBKmgdyYF9CAoAJZgoCWgDMAhsGxpM2cvxgxqdRtFrC4Abn49+-UJFgZJAawQBlKCyrY8AHmRlothAGFJHAEbSzjfCh0LEY5LAAaGBAAByhBcAhQwlwSGEkwFmTSGEVlZVokAFdaMAIYuISklJylPLq7WCD5XHgkMIQiXTq6gqhi0tc7Tx8-QOCESPL4yEIuvP19QwTYQogrGzsW0wtrN3wx+UnY6YhiElyYWqMIEDsAOho4fCmEu4A3SU10qAF8opKcpJGABGBYCAzXWCDewwVbrPbkD5fEQggBMfCAA)